# ng-options and array from controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to show list from controller in drop down. The array is controller variable as defined below:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('staticSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    self = this;
     self.options = [
        {id: 1, label: "Item 1"},
        {id: 2, label: "Item 2"},
        {id: 3, label: "Item 3"}
      ];

    $scope.data = {
     singleSelect: null,
     multipleSelect: [],
     option1: 'option-1',
    };

    $scope.forceUnknownOption = function() {
      $scope.data.singleSelect = 'nonsense';
    };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Now, I want to show this options array in drop down. The script is as below:

```html
<body ng-app="staticSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as ctrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      <label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
      <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect"
        ng-options="ctrl.option.id as ctrl.option.label for ctrl.option in ctrl.options">
      </select><br>
      <tt>selected = {{data.singleSelect}}</tt><br/>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

If options array is in `$scope` then this works fine. I am new to AngularJS. What am I doing wrong here while using controller variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how your ng-options attribute should looks like:

```
ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in ctrl.options"
```